Svelte Replace element in each with both in:{...} and out:{...}
I have a list of elements and would like to animate when this list changes. Some items might be removed, some added, some stay the same in either the same or a different position.
My thought was that I could use a combination of Svelte's animate and in/out functions for that like so:
<script>
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition';
    import { flip } from 'svelte/animate';
    
    const listOne = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    const listTwo = ['e', 'c', 'f', 'g'];

    let listIndex = $state(0);
    const list = $derived(listIndex === 0 ? listOne : listTwo);
    
    const DURATION = 3_000;
    const THIRD_OF_DURATION = DURATION / 3;
</script>

{#each list as item (item)}
    <p 
        animate:flip={{ duration: THIRD_OF_DURATION * 3, delay: THIRD_OF_DURATION}} 
        in:fade={{ duration: THIRD_OF_DURATION, delay: THIRD_OF_DURATION * 2 }} 
        out:fade={{ duration: THIRD_OF_DURATION, delay: 0 }}
    >{item}</p>
{/each}

<button onclick={() => {
    listIndex = listIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0;
}}>Toggle</button>

repl
Sadly this code is not working as expected, the problem being that the new elements are added right away and move the old existing ones out of the way (they are absolutely positioned, so they could overlap).
You could simplify this example even more by changing the lists to
const listOne = ['a'];
const listTwo = ['b'];

and removing the animate. a and b do not get swapped, instead a is moved, vanishes and then b appears.
Any ideas how to make this work correctly?

This repro doesn't have anything absolutely positioned.  Furthermore, the new elements are animated last, but I suppose that they are added right away, and this is expected.  Elements that have out transitions are kept in the DOM so they can transition into removal.  They are called "inert" elements.  I agree that having the inerts placed after the Toggle button is weird.

The thing is that elements are added immediately, and they reserve the space they will be using.  Delaying the in: transition will not change this fact, so reconsider delaying their entrance.  After all, the markup will immediately reserve their space.
